# Redirect Loop Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Estou realizando a manutenção em um sistema feito com cakephp porém ao tentar logar o brower retorna os seguinte erro.

> This webpage has a redirect loop

Procurei no `stack em ingles` e encontrei uma "solução" que dizia para eu incluir:

```
$this->Auth->allow('display');
```

Na minha classe `AppController` dentro do metodo `beforeFilter()`, isso funcionou mas agora quando logo no sistema nenhum link do menu funciona.
Abaixo o código do `AppController`

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'RequestHandler',
    'Auth'=>array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'eventos', 'action' => 'index'),
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'login'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'login'),
        'authorize' => array('Controller'),
        'authError' => 'Você não tem permissão para acessar essa área!'
    ));
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session', 'Time', 'Text', 'Number');
public $model;
public $not_condition = array('page', 'direction', 'sort');
public $filter_with_like = array();
public $conditions = array();
public $limit = 20;
public function beforeFilter() {
    //$this->Auth->allow('display');
    $this->Auth->authError = 'Área restrita';
    $this->Auth->authorize = 'Controller';
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index' );
}
```

O metodo de login:

```
public function login() {

    $this->layout = 'login';

    $this->Session->destroy();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->Behaviors->load('Containable');
        $this->User->recursive = -1;

        if ($this->Auth->login($this)) {
            $user = $this->User->checkIn($this->request->data['User']['user'], $this->request->data['User']['senha']); //Checa user e senha

            if ($user != false) { // Se tiver tudo ok
                $user['Admin'] = $user['User'];
                $this->Auth->login($user['User']);
                $this->Auth->login();

                $this->Session->read();
                $this->Session->write($this->Auth->sessionKey, $this->Auth->user());

                //$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect('/' . $th   is->Auth->user('Nivel.short') . '/dashboard/'));
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(array('controller' => 'email', 'action' => 'relatorio')));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Dados incorretos', 'login');
            }
        } else
            $this->Session->setFlash('Dados incorretos', 'login');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está declarando `LoginRedirect` duas vezes, tente tirar um, sugiro o com o caminho `'pages' => 'login'`;

```
'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'eventos', 'action' => 'index'),
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'login'),
```

para direcionar o usuário para página de login assim que ele acessar a raiz do seu sistema utilize `$this->Auth->loginAction();`